# QGIS- extract raster information into a point return nulls

Tags: qgis, raster, point, saga

I have a 1) raster layer and a 2) point layer.

I want to extract the pixel value to each point, but it is not working when using this tools (QGIS):

- plug-in "Point sampling tool" (the new shapefile is full of "null" cells)
- "SAGA > Vector to raster > Add raster values to points"

Do you know which more tools are available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Point sampling tool works perfectly if the spatial reference (projection) of the raster data and the point shapefile are same. Working with different projections for the raster(s) and shapefile data will create a shapefile with empty column of raster (Null) values.

You need to change the projection of point shapefile to be similar to the raster data to get the pixel values of the raster data into the point shapefile.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

1. convert your sample points to .txt file, that is tab delimited text file. Its a excel sheet where your sample points are in decimal degree.
2. add your txt file as layer and raster file into qgis
3. Rater analysis->sample raster values-> run the analysis by seected input and output layer.